# What is wrong with my Cherry blossom tree?

Tags: trees, tree-care

[image: Cherry blossom tree]

My cherry blossom tree's trunk is not looking very healthy and the leaves at the top are being eaten :(

Comment: Can you also post a picture that shows the entire tree and one with a closeup of the eaten leaves?

Comment: Also, add how long you've had this tree, we just had a similar question to find it was the CAT who done it. Do you have a cat or have neighborhood cats visiting?  Obviously there are insects now involved...please be a detective; dig down in the soil beneath the trunk, investigate between the bark and tree and send pictures of the leaves.  That chunky bark is heaven for insects.  That is like providing free condos and attracting insects.  A finer mulch works far better.  Go out at night with a flashlight as well.  See if you can find the insect at work, or at dinner.

Comment: Almost looks like something is eating the bark.

Answer (score -1):

Go to ACE. Get one box of Cherry Blossom Awesome (pink and green box) and follow the directions (it's basically: mix with water, apply and wrap with supplied bandage.) I had several trees in the same condition and within one month, all were healthy again. The box costs about $10 and it works! I think you can get it online directly from the manufacturer too. But I see it at ACE every time I'm in.

Comment: This does not answer the question.